# Reduce Java BigInteger to fixed length smaller number

Tags: java, math, random, biginteger, modulo

I'm attempting to implement a random number generator system; essentially I'm reading in an SHA1 hash, which then gets converted into a BigInteger value:

```
String start = "abc";
String hash = utils.SHA1(start); //Generates an SHA1 hash of the string
byte[] bytes = hash.getBytes();
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

This code generates a BigInteger with a value of:

```
811203900027758629330492243480887228261034167773619203962320290854945165232584286910163772258660
```

What I need to somehow do (and this is where I get confused), is reduce that number into a much shorter number with a fixed number of decimal places.

Using a combination of modular arithmetic and Java Math API functions, is there a sensible way of reducing this number down into a 3 digit number.  Or any other length of number I choose.

At the moment I'm just simply converting that huge number into a String, and then taking a substring of the length of number I want.  However I'm not entirely happy with this as the numbers I get aren't that random, as the range is somewhat limited with 3 digits.

The whole purpose of this is for the newly generated random x digit number to be then converted into a string using a radix of 36, to also include ASCII alphabet characters.

Any information or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: So you want 3 digits but you don't want 3 digits because they're limited? I don't understand...

Comment: He want's x digits - depending on the situation...

Comment: That integer is the ASCII hex representation of the hash value, `a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d`, so it is twice as large as needed. Googling the above reveals that it is the hash of ... well, you can google it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use modulus like `.mod(1000)` or for base 36 `.mod(36*36*36)` or even plain `.longValue() % 1000` or `.longValue() % (36*36*36)`

You can use `Long.toString(x, 10)` or `Long.toString(x, 36)`

Not sure I can tell much more without giving you the answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's just what I needed!!

Comment: Note: this is not the complete answer, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It did yes thankyou.  I just wanted some pointers on modular manipulation of huge numbers, and that's what you gave me.  I never asked for the full answer anyway, just advice :)  Thanks dude.

Comment: As the whole number should be equally random, you can use any portion of it. e.g. the first three digits are just as good as the last three.  There's lots of ways you could do it, so I would stick with the simplest.